# How to convert Time Format PT1H55M0.000S or PT12H0M0.000Sto hh:mm:ss in xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0, time-format

Can any body help me How to make this time format into hh:mm:ss in XSLT 1.0 ?

Example 1:  PT1H55M0.000S  --->  01:55:00

Example 2 :  PT12H0M0     --->  12:00:00

Comment: Why is your second example in the title different from the one in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
<xsl:variable name="input" select="'PT1H55M0.000S'" />
```

the following:

```
<output> 
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(substring-before(substring-after($input, 'T'), 'H'), '00')"/>   
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(substring-before(substring-after($input, 'H'), 'M'), ':00')"/>      
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(substring-before(substring-after($input, 'M'), 'S'), ':00')"/>

</output>
```

will result in:

```
<output>01:55:00</output>
```

**Note:**
This assumes the input contains all of the three characters: H, M and S; otherwise it's **much** more complicated.